# Select value with on change event doesn't alter the option

Tags: javascript, html

I'm having a problem, i have this html code

```
<div class="f300_sl">
   <select name="situacao_laboral" class="validate['required'] f300_sl2" onchange="alteraVencimento(this);">
<option> </option>
<option>Conta Própria</option>
<option>Prazo</option>
<option>Quadros</option>
<option>Outra</option>
  </select></div>
```

My on change event is as follows

```
    function alteraVencimento(estado){
        if(estado.value= (should be ==) 'Conta Própria'){
            document.getElementById('vencimento').innerHTML = 'Volume de Negócio:';
        }
        else{
            document.getElementById('vencimento').innerHTML = 'Vencimento:';
        }
    }
```

The select button isnt working, it always puts the value on "Conta Própria"

EDIT:
Nevermind, = instead of ==

Sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are assigning the value not comparing it, try:

```
function alteraVencimento(estado){
    if(estado.value == 'Conta Própria'){
        document.getElementById('vencimento').innerHTML = 'Volume de Negócio:';
    }
    else{
        document.getElementById('vencimento').innerHTML = 'Vencimento:';
    }
}
```

Notice the `==` rather than the `=`.

`=` assigns a variable

`==` compares